# Refresh document.element after an add with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript script that add elements in my page when I click on a button. I want to use these new elements, call them.

```
var e = document.getElementsByName('group');
```

When I execute that before and after the addition of an element with name 'group' (checked in source code), I have the same number of elements..

```
e.length /* before : return 2 */
e.length /* after... 2 :/ */
```

I think document. is not updated, is it true, have you got any solution ?

**EDIT :**

```
function newgroup() {
        var e = document.getElementsByName('group');
        var nb = e.length + 1;
        div = document.createElement("div");
        div.id = 'group'+nb;
        div.className = 'panel_drop';
        div.setAttribute('name', 'group');
        div.innerHTML = '<h5>Group '+nb+'</h5>';
        div.innerHTML += '<div class=\'drop_zone\'></div>';
        document.getElementById('groups').appendChild(div);
    }
```

I use attribut `name` to count the number of groups, I select them with their id after. But number is not updated ^^

**EDIT 2 :**

It was a mistake, I had problems with breakpoints with Chrome development tools.

Comment: Can you post the code where you are adding the element?  BTW, a tool like firebug will show you the DOM as it currently is (after adding).

Comment: The code have been added

Comment: Can you post a bit more code? I tested the code that you posted and it works fine. You get as many header elements as you want added with correct numbers.

Comment: Are you calling getElementsByName again after the addition or just querying the length property on e?

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByName` returns a live [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/NodeList), which means the results are automatically updated as you make changes to the DOM. To my knowledge, this is not something that is subject to cross-browser issues.. so the issue you're seeing is likely to be unrelated. From [the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/dom.html#dom-document-getelementsbyname):

> The getElementsByName(name) method takes a string name, and must
>   return a live NodeList containing all the HTML elements in that
>   document that have a name attribute whose value is equal to the name
>   argument (in a case-sensitive manner), in tree order. When the method
>   is invoked on a Document object again with the same argument, the user
>   agent may return the same as the object returned by the earlier call.
>   In other cases, a new NodeList object must be returned.

Eaxmple:

http://jsfiddle.net/hhdPB/

```
var e = document.getElementsByName('group');

console.log(e.length); // 0

var el = document.createElement('span');
el.setAttribute('name', 'group');

document.body.appendChild(el);

console.log(e.length); // 1

document.body.appendChild(el.cloneNode(false));

console.log(e.length); // 2
```

Also, the code you posted up seems to work fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/GyTBw/1

```
function newgroup() {
    var e = document.getElementsByName('group');
    var nb = e.length + 1;
    console.log(nb);
    div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = 'group' + nb;
    div.className = 'panel_drop';
    div.setAttribute('name', 'group');
    div.innerHTML = '<h5>Group ' + nb + '</h5>';
    div.innerHTML += '<div class=\'drop_zone\'></div>';
    document.getElementById('groups').appendChild(div);
}

for (var i = 0; i != 5; i++) {
    newgroup(); // 1 2 3 4 5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was an error with my manipulation of chrome developers tools, with breaks.. thanks and sorry

Comment: Not a problem and you don't need to apologize :) However, I suggest that you post this as an edit to your question rather than a separate answer. Also, if you feel like your question was answered, hit the checkmark. Alternatively, you can give more details regarding your mistake and submit it as an answer, so that someone could benefit from it in the future.

Answer (score -3):

You should use JQuery and Classes instead of ElementNames.

So for example:

```
<div class="MyDivs">abc</div>
<div class="MyDivs">def</div>
<div class="MyDivs">ghi</div>
```

would be selected by:

```
var Divs = $(".MyDivs");
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, why DOM is not updated